# Android ListView not displaying data...pretty new at this and certain I'm doing something wrong

Tags: java, android

This is my second app, and first to use ListActivity. Something somewhere  isn't playing nicely - the activity (ShowWidget) displays - but the list is empty.

Here's my ListActivity code:

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ShowWidget extends ListActivity  {
  DataProvider db = new DataProvider(ShowWidget.this);
  public static String sound;
  MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  private ListView LV;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Loading your settings.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      LV = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, PENS));
        getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);

      // change to our configure view
      setContentView(R.layout.widget_show);

      /*db.open();
      Cursor cursor = db.getRecord(1);
      ShowWidget.sound  = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("sound"));
      cursor.close();
      db.close();*/
    }

    static final String[] PENS = new String[]{
      "MONT Blanc", "Gucci", "Parker", "Sailor",
      "Porsche Design", "Rotring", "Sheaffer", "Waterman"
    };

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
      super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
      Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
      String pen = o.toString();
      Toast.makeText(this, "You have chosen the pen: " + " " + pen, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

  public void play(){
    }
}
```

and my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/widgetShow">

    <ListView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_weight="1">

  </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Like I said, I'm doing something wrong here - the activity displays, but not the data stored in PENS. Any idea or point in the right direction would be very much appreciated! If the question is not clear, please comment and I'll edit question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the order of things in which you're dealing with the UI components. First you inflate the `ListView` from the **default** layout (import to realize) but after that, you basically tell the `Activity` to use some other layout, called `R.layout.widget_show`. As a result, what you're seeing onscreen is not what you're setting the adapter to.

The reason why you're not getting an actual error is because you're extending `ListActivity`, which defines a default layout that includes a `ListView`. In any regular `Activity` you would get a `NullPointerException` because no content view has been set yet, so the `Activity` wouldn't know where to inflate the view(s) from.

Change your code as follows:

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // tell activity to use your custom layout:
    setContentView(R.layout.widget_show);      
    // set adapter etc   
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, PENS));
    getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
}
```

Since you declared the `ListView` in your layout file with id `@android:id/list` (which is also a requirement for using `ListActivity`), you get some convenience methods for free, amongst which is you not having to manually inflate the `ListView`. Hence you can just use `getListView()` after having set the content view.

Answer (score 1):

Try editing your layout file like so:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/widgetShow">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/list">

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I do believe this (along with @cod3-monk-ey) answer fixed it - it's showing perfectly now :) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, PENS));
```

To:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, PENS);
```